# ScrollViewer in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, stackpanel

```
<StackPanel Name="mypanel">
   <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName=mypanel, Path=ActualHeight}">
```

I need, `Height = mypanel.ActualHeight-60`.

How can I do it?

**EDIT:**

```
<StackPanel Name="mypanel">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding HeaderPart}" /> <= here must be Expander
    <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName=mypanel, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}}" >
        <StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When there is no `Expander`, all is working. When the `Expander` is, `mypanel.ActualHeight`, `HeightAdjustmentConverter = 0`.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that takes in the `ActualHeight` and returns a new value of that minus 60.

Something like:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class HeightAdjustmentConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double original = (double)value;
        return double - 60;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double adjusted = (double)value;
        return adjusted + 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: In XAML it will be like this?

<ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName=mypanel, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource HeightAdjustmentConverter}}"

Comment: @Kira Yep, that would be right, with a line somewhere to actually create the static resource.